# Slow query performance of simple SELECT query (Postgresql 9.6)

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

In a app called 'Links', users post links of interesting content they've discovered recently (and other vote on the said posts).

These posted links are saved in a `links_link` table in my postgresql 9.6.5 DB.

One innocuous looking `SELECT` query on the `links_link` table is consistently showing up in `slow_log`. It's taking longer than 500ms, and is ~10X slower than what I'm experiencing in most other postgresql operations.

Here's an example of the corresponding SQL from my slow log:

**LOG:  duration: 8648.676 ms  statement:**

```
SELECT "links_link"."id",
       "links_link"."description",
       "links_link"."submitted_on",
       "links_link"."reply_count",
       "links_link"."net_votes"
FROM   "links_link"
WHERE  "links_link"."submitter_id" = 811645
ORDER  BY "links_link"."id" DESC
LIMIT  1
```

See the the `explain analyze` results: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Xp5v

The query ends up filtering 14,331,127 rows according to that!

**What I've tried:**

My gut feel is that Postgres bases this query plan on misleading statistics. Thus, I've run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the said table. However this hasn't changed anything.

Being an accidental DBA of sorts, I'm looking for some quick expert guidance on the subject. Thanks in advance and apologies for the noob question (if it is).

**Edit:**

Here's the entire output for `\d links_link`:

```
                                         Table "public.links_link"
        Column        |           Type           |                        Modifiers                        
----------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id                   | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_link_id_seq'::regclass)
 description          | text                     | not null
 submitter_id         | integer                  | not null
 submitted_on         | timestamp with time zone | not null
 rank_score           | double precision         | not null
 url                  | character varying(250)   | not null
 cagtegory            | character varying(25)    | not null
 image_file           | character varying(100)   | 
 reply_count          | integer                  | default 0
 device               | character varying(10)    | default '1'::character varying
 latest_reply_id      | integer                  | 
 which_photostream_id | integer                  | 
 is_visible           | boolean                  | default true
 net_votes            | integer                  | default 0
Indexes:
    "links_link_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_link_latest_reply_id_idx" btree (latest_reply_id)
    "links_link_submitter_id" btree (submitter_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "link_whichphotostreamid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_photostream_id) REFERENCES links_photostream(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "links_link_submitter_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (submitter_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "publicreplyposter_link_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (latest_reply_id) REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "links_publicreply" CONSTRAINT "links_publicreply_answer_to_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (answer_to_id) REFERENCES links_link(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_report" CONSTRAINT "links_report_which_link_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_link_id) REFERENCES links_link(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_vote" CONSTRAINT "links_vote_link_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (link_id) REFERENCES links_link(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_photoobjectsubscription" CONSTRAINT "which_link_id_photoobjectsubscription" FOREIGN KEY (which_link_id) REFERENCES links_link(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: See if an index on `(submitter_id, id DESC)` helps.

Comment: Just to confirm so nothing is screwed, you're implying I do `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY link_id_submitter_id ON links_link (submitter_id, id DESC)`?

Comment: Yes, that looks good.

Comment: Just imagine how you'd search for the result in that index -- traverse it to find the subtree for the `submitter_id` and then just pick the first node, as they're sorted by `id DESC`. What do you mean by undo? You can just drop it if you don't want it any more, if that's what you're asking (cannot be used anymore afterwards of course).

Comment: That should be alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could imagine an index on `links_link (submitter_id, id DESC)` being of great help here.

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY link_id_submitter_id
                          ON links_link (submitter_id, id DESC);
```

It can be traversed to quickly find the subtree for `submitter_id = 811645`. Then the first node can be picked instantly to get the first record ordered by `id DESC`.

Comment: Yes, this is a very effective solution.  The "DESC" is probably not necessary there, and if it isn't I think it is better to omit it. In most cases PostgreSQL can follow an index in either direction. Once he has an index on `(submitter_id, id)` he can probably drop the one on just `(submitter_id)`, no point in maintaining an index that is redundant.